# Saml request signing with certificate stored in the Database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using multiple Identity Providers in my application. The SAML Login and Assertion is working absolutely fine. My question is regarding signing the SAML messages using the certificates.

1. I am storing the certificate for each Idp in the database and want to load it at the runtime. In the Demo application, the certificate is saved on the physical path and loaded using,

   ```
   CertificateUtil.Load
   ```

   This method has 5 overloads but it asks for the path where the certificate is stored. Can I use the method,

   ```
   CertificateUtil.LoadBytes
   ```

   to load the certificate from the string? Because I can't see any example for that?
2. The certificate needs to be installed on the system?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the certificate in the database as a base64 encode string.

To create a base64 encode string from a certificate file (including the private key):

```
var certificate = ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Util.CertificateUtil.Load("... certificate file path ...", "... password ...", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
var base64EncodeCertificate = Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));
```

To get a certificate from a base64 encode string:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodeCertificate));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have loaded the certificate with Base64 string. The issue is that I am unable to sign the request using the certificate. I have checked your answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57495219/1361888
From where I get the private key? Do I need to generate it myself?

Comment: I have corrected the answer to both export the public and private key.

Comment: Sorry I was not able to explain properly. In the database, I have stored the certificate as Base64 encoded string. Do I need to save this encoded string as a file on the filesystem to be loaded?

Comment: You kan just new up the X509Certificate2 based on the base64 string, you do not need a file.

Comment: Hi, is there a security issue if i use the email from the saml to search through my database for the x509 certificate before i validate the saml response?

Comment: Yes, it is not secure. You need to concatenate a unique string/key for the IdP connection that you chose.  A string/key the external party cannot change. E.g., extidp1_some@other.com